# When new account is created inform everyone

Tags: visualforce, formula

I was thinking to create something like the following.
When a new account was created a message to inform every sales agent that we have a new client in the company.That message to be shown as visual page or formula or somehow on all tabs or on leads or i don't know somewhere where is really visible for everyone. Anyone have an idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Darko

Comment: You can write a trigger to send email after new Account Creation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - You can try for Visualforce Area Home Page Component, which you can accommodate as homepage - sidebar component. It will have its own custom controller in which you can write the query to retrieve the records created today or as per your requirement. You can restrict the number of record retrieved by giving limit in SOQL and give hyperlink to custom page where you can display all the newly created records.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_page_components_custom_vf_overview.htm&language=en_US

Thanks,

Manish